# Copying Formulas in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a requirement please, I want to copy formulas from one cell to another Example:

I have 4 sheets in my spreadsheet, E.g. Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 & Sheet4 now let’s assume that in the 1st sheet I write a formula in A7 Cell

```
=If(G7=1,"True","False")
```

where G7 has either 1 or 0.

I want the same to get copied in 2nd, 3rd and 4th sheet in A7 Cell.

I know I can copy and paste them however in the real use case the formula is called so many times at different places that any change in the formula makes it really difficult to copy them to all the places.

So I want that I will change the formula in Sheet1 ONLY and the change will get replicated in the other 3 Sheets.

I have tried creating a custom function however since it’s a lot of data and so many calls to the function, makes it really slow. I don’t know what could be the best option for my problem. Hence need your help, please.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

that's not possible but you can do this:

- put your formula in G7
- copypaste this formula on 1000 different locations (where you need them)
- then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can't 'send' a formula with a formula, only 'fetch' its result, so you would need something like Google Apps Script (and questions about that here should routinely show an attempt at writing the code).

Comment: Hello would you be able to help with some code and how to execute them please?